# Meaningless errors in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a basic todo list in javascript in afternoon but when i opened my pc that around 8:00 pm i got a error  which seems to be malicious for me please check and tell me that why it is happening

index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ToDo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Grandstander:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onload="changebg()">
    <div class="main">
        <h1 id="namelem" style="font-size: 30px;"></h1>
        <div class="list">
            <h id="msg" style="font-size:40px;font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;"></h><br>
            <h style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">Your todo list cannot contain more than 8 tasks, it can tire you </h>
            <hr>
            <ul class="todolist">
                <li>Wake up</li>
                <br>
                <li id="1"></li>
                <li id="2"></li>
                <li id="3"></li>
                <li id="4"></li>
                <li id="5"></li>
                <li id="6"></li>
                <li id="7"></li>
                <li id="8"></li>
                <li>Sleep</li><br>
            </ul>         
            <hr><br>
            <input type="text" id="taskinp" placeholder="Enter your task here">
            <input type="button" value="Sumbit" class="sumbit_btn" onclick="takeTask()">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" id="remtsk" placeholder="Enter task number to remove">
            <input type="button" value="Remove" class="delbtn" onclick="takeremTsk()">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="logic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:-

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.main{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.list{
    height: 650px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #6a89cc;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    left: 40%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border-left: 15px dashed yellow;
}

.todolist{
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Grandstander', cursive;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type:square;
}

#taskinp{
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    background-color: lavenderblush;
    color: black;
}

.sumbit_btn{
    width: 96px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: chocolate;
}

#remtsk {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    background-color: lavenderblush;
    color: black;
}

.delbtn{
    width: 96px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: chocolate;
}
```

and

logic.js:-

```
let name = prompt("Could you enter your name, please try to write only 9 charecter in your name");
alert("Do not enter too long task to mentain your daily tasks beautifully!");
let msg = document.getElementById('msg');
msg.innerHTML = "Todo list of " + name;
document.getElementById('namelem').innerHTML = "Todo list of " + name + dateNow;

const todoitem1 = document.getElementById('1');
const todoitem2 = document.getElementById('2');
const todoitem3 = document.getElementById('3');
const todoitem4 = document.getElementById('4');
const todoitem5 = document.getElementById('5');
const todoitem6 = document.getElementById('6');
const todoitem7 = document.getElementById('7');
const todoitem8 = document.getElementById('8');

const takeTask = () => {
    const task = document.getElementById('taskinp').value;
    addTask()
};

const addTask = () => {
    const task = document.getElementById('taskinp').value;
    if(todoitem1.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem1.innerHTML = "1] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem2.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem2.innerHTML = "2] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem3.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem3.innerHTML = "3] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem4.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem4.innerHTML = "4] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem5.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem5.innerHTML  = "5] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem6.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem6.innerHTML = "6] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem7.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem7.innerHTML = "7] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem8.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem8.innerHTML = "8] " + task;
    }
    else{
        alert("You have exceeded your limits !");
    }
};

const takeremTsk = () => {
    const removetotask = document.getElementById('remtsk').value;
    removetask()
};

const removetask = () => {
    const removetotask = document.getElementById('remtsk').value;
    if(removetotask == 1){
        todoitem1.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 2){
        todoitem2.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 3){
        todoitem3.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 4){
        todoitem4.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 5){
        todoitem5.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 6){
        todoitem6.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 7){
        todoitem7.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 8){
        todoitem8.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else{
        alert("Invalid Choice!");
    }
};

const changebg = () => {
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

    colors = ['purple', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'orange','yellow','red','aqua','royalblue','white', 'darkgreen','lightgreen'];

    randCol = colors[randNum];

    document.body.style.background = randCol;
}
```

i was getting error that

```
Unresolved reference changebg in body:onload
```

and another one was

`Unresolved reference takeTask()`

This piece of code was working fine in afternoon but now i opened it without doing any change in any of the files i got error which has no meaning

and other mess was onclicks that i have assigned some onclick functions on buttons but when i click them it says `Unresolved reference` but i have checked that they are defined and also checked that javascript executes after the page loads properly. So please help me

Thanks!

Comment: it's because there is an error in javascript code

Comment: What is an `<h></h>` element?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a meaningless error message!!

There are however confusing ones, and in your case it was the use of the variable `dateNow` right near the top of your script which is not defined anywhere. By this error occurring early on, nothing below it is interpreted and thus when you come to use methods like `changebg` lower down, they do not exist. Fix this error (in the example below I just commented out the offending line) and it all works.

```js
let name = prompt("Could you enter your name, please try to write only 9 charecter in your name");
alert("Do not enter too long task to mentain your daily tasks beautifully!");
let msg = document.getElementById('msg');
msg.innerHTML = "Todo list of " + name;
//document.getElementById('namelem').innerHTML = "Todo list of " + name + dateNow;

const todoitem1 = document.getElementById('1');
const todoitem2 = document.getElementById('2');
const todoitem3 = document.getElementById('3');
const todoitem4 = document.getElementById('4');
const todoitem5 = document.getElementById('5');
const todoitem6 = document.getElementById('6');
const todoitem7 = document.getElementById('7');
const todoitem8 = document.getElementById('8');

const takeTask = () => {
    const task = document.getElementById('taskinp').value;
    addTask()
};

const addTask = () => {
    const task = document.getElementById('taskinp').value;
    if(todoitem1.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem1.innerHTML = "1] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem2.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem2.innerHTML = "2] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem3.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem3.innerHTML = "3] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem4.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem4.innerHTML = "4] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem5.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem5.innerHTML  = "5] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem6.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem6.innerHTML = "6] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem7.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem7.innerHTML = "7] " + task;
    }
    else if(todoitem8.innerHTML == ""){
        todoitem8.innerHTML = "8] " + task;
    }
    else{
        alert("You have exceeded your limits !");
    }
};

const takeremTsk = () => {
    const removetotask = document.getElementById('remtsk').value;
    removetask()
};

const removetask = () => {
    const removetotask = document.getElementById('remtsk').value;
    if(removetotask == 1){
        todoitem1.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 2){
        todoitem2.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 3){
        todoitem3.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 4){
        todoitem4.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 5){
        todoitem5.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 6){
        todoitem6.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 7){
        todoitem7.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if(removetotask == 8){
        todoitem8.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else{
        alert("Invalid Choice!");
    }
};

const changebg = () => {
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

    colors = ['purple', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'orange','yellow','red','aqua','royalblue','white', 'darkgreen','lightgreen'];

    randCol = colors[randNum];

    document.body.style.background = randCol;
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.main{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.list{
    height: 650px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #6a89cc;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    left: 40%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border-left: 15px dashed yellow;
}

.todolist{
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Grandstander', cursive;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type:square;
}

#taskinp{
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    background-color: lavenderblush;
    color: black;
}

.sumbit_btn{
    width: 96px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: chocolate;
}

#remtsk {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    background-color: lavenderblush;
    color: black;
}

.delbtn{
    width: 96px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ToDo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Grandstander:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onload="changebg()">
    <div class="main">
        <h1 id="namelem" style="font-size: 30px;"></h1>
        <div class="list">
            <h id="msg" style="font-size:40px;font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;"></h><br>
            <h style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">Your todo list cannot contain more than 8 tasks, it can tire you </h>
            <hr>
            <ul class="todolist">
                <li>Wake up</li>
                <br>
                <li id="1"></li>
                <li id="2"></li>
                <li id="3"></li>
                <li id="4"></li>
                <li id="5"></li>
                <li id="6"></li>
                <li id="7"></li>
                <li id="8"></li>
                <li>Sleep</li><br>
            </ul>         
            <hr><br>
            <input type="text" id="taskinp" placeholder="Enter your task here">
            <input type="button" value="Sumbit" class="sumbit_btn" onclick="takeTask()">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" id="remtsk" placeholder="Enter task number to remove">
            <input type="button" value="Remove" class="delbtn" onclick="takeremTsk()">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="logic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh sorry that was a little mistake

Answer (score 1):

dateNow is not defined. I hope you missed `const dateNow = Date();` for date with time or
`const dateNow = Date.now();` to generate  milliseconds elapsed.
Refer my code.

```js
let name = prompt(
  "Could you enter your name, please try to write only 9 charecter in your name"
);
alert("Do not enter too long task to mentain your daily tasks beautifully!");
let msg = document.getElementById("msg");
msg.innerHTML = "Todo list of " + name;
dateNow = Date();
document.getElementById("namelem").innerHTML = "Todo list of " + name + dateNow;

const todoitem1 = document.getElementById("1");
const todoitem2 = document.getElementById("2");
const todoitem3 = document.getElementById("3");
const todoitem4 = document.getElementById("4");
const todoitem5 = document.getElementById("5");
const todoitem6 = document.getElementById("6");
const todoitem7 = document.getElementById("7");
const todoitem8 = document.getElementById("8");

const takeTask = () => {
  const task = document.getElementById("taskinp").value;
  addTask();
};

const addTask = () => {
  const task = document.getElementById("taskinp").value;
  if (todoitem1.innerHTML == "") {
    todoitem1.innerHTML = "1] " + task;
  } else if (todoitem2.innerHTML == "") {
    todoitem2.innerHTML = "2] " + task;
  } else if (todoitem3.innerHTML == "") {
    todoitem3.innerHTML = "3] " + task;
  } else if (todoitem4.innerHTML == "") {
    todoitem4.innerHTML = "4] " + task;
  } else if (todoitem5.innerHTML == "") {
    todoitem5.innerHTML = "5] " + task;
  } else if (todoitem6.innerHTML == "") {
    todoitem6.innerHTML = "6] " + task;
  } else if (todoitem7.innerHTML == "") {
    todoitem7.innerHTML = "7] " + task;
  } else if (todoitem8.innerHTML == "") {
    todoitem8.innerHTML = "8] " + task;
  } else {
    alert("You have exceeded your limits !");
  }
};

const takeremTsk = () => {
  const removetotask = document.getElementById("remtsk").value;
  removetask();
};

const removetask = () => {
  const removetotask = document.getElementById("remtsk").value;
  if (removetotask == 1) {
    todoitem1.innerHTML = "";
  } else if (removetotask == 2) {
    todoitem2.innerHTML = "";
  } else if (removetotask == 3) {
    todoitem3.innerHTML = "";
  } else if (removetotask == 4) {
    todoitem4.innerHTML = "";
  } else if (removetotask == 5) {
    todoitem5.innerHTML = "";
  } else if (removetotask == 6) {
    todoitem6.innerHTML = "";
  } else if (removetotask == 7) {
    todoitem7.innerHTML = "";
  } else if (removetotask == 8) {
    todoitem8.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    alert("Invalid Choice!");
  }
};
const changebg = () => {
  randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

  colors = [
    "purple",
    "indigo",
    "blue",
    "green",
    "orange",
    "yellow",
    "red",
    "aqua",
    "royalblue",
    "white",
    "darkgreen",
    "lightgreen",
  ];

  randCol = colors[randNum];

  document.body.style.background = randCol;
};
```

```css
.todolist{
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Grandstander', cursive;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type:square;
}

#taskinp{
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    background-color: lavenderblush;
    color: black;
}

.sumbit_btn{
    width: 96px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: chocolate;
}

#remtsk {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    background-color: lavenderblush;
    color: black;
}

.delbtn{
    width: 96px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>ToDo List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Grandstander:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body onload="changebg()">
    <div class="main">
        <h1 id="namelem" style="font-size: 30px;"></h1>
        <div class="list">
            <h id="msg" style="font-size:40px;font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;"></h><br>
            <h style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">Your todo list cannot contain more than 8 tasks, it can tire you
            </h>
            <hr>
            <ul class="todolist">
                <li>Wake up</li>
                <br>
                <li id="1"></li>
                <li id="2"></li>
                <li id="3"></li>
                <li id="4"></li>
                <li id="5"></li>
                <li id="6"></li>
                <li id="7"></li>
                <li id="8"></li>
                <li>Sleep</li><br>
            </ul>
            <hr><br>
            <input type="text" id="taskinp" placeholder="Enter your task here">
            <input type="button" value="Sumbit" class="sumbit_btn" onclick="takeTask()">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" id="remtsk" placeholder="Enter task number to remove">
            <input type="button" value="Remove" class="delbtn" onclick="takeremTsk()">
        </div>
    </div>
        <script src="todo.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: oh sorry that was a little mistake